# Convert three letter language code to language identifier (LANGID)

Tags: c++, winapi, internationalization

Is there some way in the Win32 API to convert a three letter language code, as returned by `GetLocaleInfo()` with `LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME` specified, to a corresponding `LANGID` or `LCID`? That is, going in "reverse" to what `GetLocaleInfo()` normally does?

What I'm trying to do is to parse what kind of language a resource DLL is using, and so far, without touching anything about the DLL, going by the dll name with a format `nameLNG.dll`, where `LNG` is a three letter language code, seems to be the easiest method, assuming such a function exists.

If this isn't easy to do, I guess Plan B is to give our language DLL's a version info resource, specify their respective cultures there, and later on in the application, read which cultures they use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no direct Win32 API that gives you a LANGID given a 3-letters abbreviation.

It looks like [CLanguageSupport](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/locale/LanguageMenu.aspx) is your friend [today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553656) :-) It already implements your plan B to lookup the LANGID based on the contents of the version info resource.

The piece of code you're looking for is int the function

```
LANGID CLanguageSupport::GetLangIdFromFile(LPCTSTR pszFilename)
```

Of course, the drawback is that you may have a mismatch between the version info and the DLL name. But you'd very quickly catch it during tests. And if you let a tool such as [appTranslator](http://www.apptranslator.com) create the DLLs for you, you're sure to be on the safe side.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll end up using this class then, since you have apparently already side-stepped not only one, but two of the issues we're now facing. We may even re-implement the language submenu that I just days ago took away, thinking our switch to the MFC mechanism would be final. Oh well...

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate the installed locales using [`EnumSystemLocales()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317828(VS.85).aspx) and build the map yourself.  I do this during application initialization in a service that I wrote a while ago and it has worked out well thus far.

I would recommend using *Plan B* in this case.  I usually steer clear of encoding stuff into the file name.  If for no other reason, using the 3-character [ISO-639](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639) variant isn't perfect unless you strictly specify which variant you are using - [ISO-639-2/B, ISO-639-2/T](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-2), or [ISO-639-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-3).

If you need to provide locale-specific variants, then you should take a close look at [RFC3066](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3066).  Basically, you need to specify the language and country code and, in some cases, the region code as well.  In any case, the LCID encapsulates all of this goodness.

The one thing that I am not completely certain of is whether the langID in the resource information is a full LCID or not.  The codes listed in the [VERSIONINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058(VS.85).aspx) reference are LCIDs so I would try using an LCID in the VERSIONINFO header.  If not, you can always include the information as a string in the string block.

Comment: EnumSystemLocales only give me a list of three letter acronyms, right? I'm unsure how to build a map by using only this information, and lacking the LCID's or LANGID's to translate from? This solution would be perfect if the callback function for EnumSystemLocales would have returned a *pair* of LCID's and "ISO" strings.

Comment: The argument to the `EnumLocalesProc` is actually the LCID formatted as a hexadecimal number into a string.  The documentation is less than clear about this - _"Pointer to a buffer containing a null-terminated locale identifier string"_.  What they fail to mention is that you have to call something like `_tcstoul(lpLocaleString, NULL, 16)` on it to get the locale identifier into a usable form.  Once you have the LCID, you can get what you need from `GetLocaleInfo()` using `LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME` and `LOCALE_SISO3166CTRYNAME`.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the LangID by calling `GetLocaleInfo()` with `LOCAL_RETURN_NUMBER|LOCALE_ILANGUAGE` for the *LCType* parameter, just as you passed `LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME` to obtain the three-letter ISO code.  By passing the same *lcid* to this function, you can store the corresponding LangID with the ISO code.

Note that MSDN says `LOCALE_ILANGUAGE` should not be used in favor `LOCALE_SLANG` on Vista and above, but I believe the comment does not apply for use of `LOCALE_ILANGUAGE` with `LOCALE_RETURN_NUMBER`.

As your project evolves, you might generate several localized files for each language.  For this reason, I would suggest you store your localized files in subdirectories named after the language.  Microsoft has used directories named after the LangID's, for example "1033" as the English resources directory.  I think it would be more friendly to use the three-letter code, such as "ENU\name.dll".  In any case, subdirectories are a simple solution and hopefully won't complicate your build process as much as changing the target file name.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have access to the LCID, but want a LANGID from the language code three letter acronym (the faux-ISO code).

Comment: FWIW, MS wants us to move away from LOCALE_ILANGUAGE because they want to shift to string-only "lang ids", a la .NET cultures ids. iow they try to convince us that LANGID *may* die some day, at least for newly supported languages in Win8+